# How to enlarge(zoom) a section of a video and overlay it on the original video using Directshow.Net

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I currently developed a media player using directshow.net. The videos have a small timestamp at the top left corner, which is very small. I need to enlarge it, so that it is visible/readable while the video plays.

I have tried using:

```
IVMRFilterConfig
IVMRMixerControl
```

And get two windows of the same video playing, but I can't seem to zoom into the one window and only display the timestamp section.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved (sort of) my problem by letting two independant video windows run at the same time. Thus window1 displays the whole image and window2 is a small window in the corner of the screen and it only displays the date time zoomed in.

I just had to make sure they play and stop at the same time and when I used frame skips, that both videos are treated.